# In VBA editor window, mouse selects next line instead of part of current one

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-office

This is my problem:

[image: Mouse selects wrong line]

So, I want to select just a part of one (usually very long) line, and when I only slightly move my mouse down while moving to the right, the next line gets selected, and I can start over again.

Does anyone have a solution for this annoying mouse behavior?

Or would you recommend an altogether different input method? (pen, touch pad, keyboard, etc.)

Comment: VBA sees this as all one line even though visually it is split over two. This is due to the ` _` character at the end of the first line

Comment: No, that's not it, but I understand from your answer that my example caused you to think this was the case. But it happens also when there's two unrelated lines. I'll change my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the start point of the text you want, then with the SHIFT key held down, click on the end point.

Comment: Yes! Where have you been all my life! Thank you! I was familiar with the Keyboard version of your suggestion (select starting point and press right arrow key while holding control+shift) but didn't know the answer to my favorite annoyance was THIS simple.

Comment: Darn, I can't up vote your answer, because of too few points.... I need to hang out here more...

Answer (score 0):

That's by design.

If you only wish to mark a part of one line, move mouse left-right only, not down (or up).

Comment: My problem is that I'm actually TRYING (but failing) to keep my mouse on one line! This happens especially on long lines when the "distance" to cover  to the right, is longer. One wobble and I'm on a different line. Annoying as heck.

Comment: Lower your mouse sensitivity - are you using a trackpad or a mouse?

Comment: I see. Then move/mark to the right edge of the line to mark, and gently move up until one line is marked only.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to target your problem.

1. You can use your `Shift`-Key and the cursor keys to select.
2. You can also use your `Shift`-Key in combination with your `End`-Key and or `Pos1`-Key
3. You can also use your `Shift`-Key in combination with your mouse like mentioned by another user
4. Also the problem is not that big when you make shorter lines. In VBA you can use `_` to hang lines together and interpret it like one:

   ```
   txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam   nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, " _
       & "sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et " _
       & "dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero " _
       & "eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet " _
       & "clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem " _
       & "ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur " _
       & "sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut " _
       & "labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At " _
       & "vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet " _
       & "clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum " _
       & "dolor sit amet."
   ```
5. To select the whole line you can also click at the white space between the gray bar on the left side of the editor and the first sign in the editor

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the list of all the possible solutions. Number 3 was the one I was looking for. I was aware of the others.

Comment: May you select any answer as the answer?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I just did so. And eventhough your answer is the most complete one, I chose Marks answer, because this was the particular solution I had been looking for for so long.